# A Halloween Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, seasonal

> My first's where you are when you aren't trick-or-treating
>   My next is the start of what kids will be eating
>   My third, when gigantic, might test your comport
>   My fourth starts the *season* where goblins cavort
>   My fifth is a note sung by sirens that lure you
>   My last's where you put the disguise that obscures you
>
> My whole is a staple of magic primeval
>   For witches invoking the forces of evil

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to Dr Xorile for seeing the final solution from my first attempt and GentlePurpleRain for the last fix in formatting:

My first's where you are when you aren't trick-or-treating

> **IN**, because when you're not *out* trick-or-treating, you're *in*.

My next is the start of what kids will be eating

> **C**, the "start" of *candy*.

My third, when gigantic, might test your comport

> **ANT**, as in a comport-testing gigantic *ant*.

My fourth starts the season where goblins cavort

> **A**, the "start" of *autumn*.

My fifth is a note sung by sirens that lure you

> **TI**, one of the notes do, re mi, fa so, la *ti*, do

My last's where you put the disguise that obscures you

> **ON**, because you put the disguise *on* to obscure your identity.

My whole is a staple of magic primeval

For witches invoking the forces of evil

> **INCANTATION**

Comment: Could it be ant instead of bee? To make incantati? Or maybe incantation if the last is "eye on"

Comment: @DrXorile, Incantation sounds pretty good to me. I assumed based on the puzzle wording ("third", "forth", etc.) that each clue could only yield one letter, but I'm editing my answer to see if that's the correct solution.

Comment: Almost!  Your final solution is correct, but the fifth and sixth aren't quite right.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, how's the last edit?

Comment: Now you've got it!  I'd suggest removing all the strikeout text, as it's just confusing for people.  The original answer is still in the edit history if people are interested.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain if you can figure out the answer while having any of the clues wrong, it's not a well-written riddle in my book. all that matters when answering a riddle is the answer, right? the sphinx never asked anyone to explain their reasoning. :)

Comment: @sgroves I agree, and I probably could have done better with the fifth and sixth clues. That being said, getting **`ION`** from "you put a disguise *on* your *eyes* is really stretching.  I do take issue with your comment about figuring out the answer while having clues wrong, though. Since this riddle involves trying to guess one word, it seems quite reasonable that having 4 or 5 of the clues correct would be sufficient to guess the solution, even though not all clues have been solved. And on Puzzling.SE, the solution is *not* all that matters. *How* we arrive at it is just as important.